# Maya Script to select a channel?

Tags: python, selection, maya, channel, mel

I am looking for a way to select a channel in Maya ( ex, Translate Y  or Rotate Z  or something like that ) instead of manually selecting a channel by using a mouse click-in attribute editor.

Does anyone know a script that allows me to do so?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's **no command** allowing you select a channel in Channel Box or in Attribute Editor (you should check ***Echo All Commands*** in Script Editor to test it).

You are just allowed to directly set (without selection) a value using this MEL command:

```
setAttr "pSphere1.translateY" 12 ;
```

or this way using Python command:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
cmds.setAttr('pSphere1.translateY', 12)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition of what say Andy, from my knowledge, you cannot find that.
Im not sure what kind of manipulation you are trying to do but an alternative to setting a value with cmds.setAttr
You can also find what is selected inside the channelBox with :

```
from maya import cmds, mel
gChannelBoxName = mel.eval('$temp=$gChannelBoxName')
nameObject = cmds.channelBox(gChannelBoxName, q=1, hol=1) # a lot of flags exists depending of what you are looking for
```

https://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2009help/commandspython/channelBox.html